# Is it possible to change the Gogs HTTP_PORT for the Docker Install?

Tags: gogs

I tried changing the HTTP_PORT server configuration to use port 80 on both a current install and a fresh install, but Gogs is still listening on port 3000?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but since Gogs runs as a non root user (git), the user must somehow be allowed to bind to port 80.  More details here:
https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/3196#issuecomment-226776430